# How to create an image element before the <li> list

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a list of accounts in bootstrap popover and I have a `<li>` element created in the `<ul>` tag.

```
var t = ul.append($(document.createElement('li')).text('Test Account'));
```

I was hoping to add an image before every `<li>` element, something like this:

[image]

I have account names listed and I would like to add an image before the account text( the green color icon).
Any ideas on how i can achieve this?

Comment: Anything to do with CSS here?

Comment: Put the image element inside the `<li>` element and float it to the left. Or set it as the element's background image. Having it outside the list item would be incorrect html.

Comment: How can i achieve that?

Comment: @user2942566 He just told you... `Put the image element inside the <li> element and float it to the left. Or set it as the element's background image.` That is basic css.

Comment: @ViruZX: Comment only if you have something constructive to say. Dont repeat the same comment mentioned above.I dont need opinions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is this: [View code here via JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8Lkc5no/). I just grabbed a blue icon I found on Google images, but of course, you can use any image you like.

```
ul li {
   list-style-type: none; // this removes the default li bullet so you can use your own custom image
   background-image: url('images/bullet_image.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: top left;
   padding-left: 30px; // Use as many pixels as you need to provide enough space between the image and the text.
}
```

Ok so the second block of code will add a background image of your new custom bullet point, or your new image to the left of your LI. So this would put the image right behind your first two or three letters and what the padding-left:30px does it moves it over to the left and provides room for the image without the text overlapping onto it.

I've developed hundreds of web sites and for some reason, this technique worked the best for placing an image to the left of your li's aka a custom list-style-image but with a more precise execution for placement of the image.

Comment: Ok, I just edited this answer like 5 times, lastly, adding a JSFiddle example URL. So this comment should prompt you to re-load this page and see the updated answer if you haven't already.

Comment: No problema man :) Thanks for the recognition.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image inside the li tag for each one like this example

```
<html>
<body>

<h4>list and images</h4>
<ul>
<li><img src="coffee.jpg" height="15px" weight = "15px" /> &nbsp; Coffee</li>
<li><img src="Tea.jpg" height="15px" weight = "15px" /> &nbsp; Tea</li>
<li><img src="milk.jpg" height="15px" weight = "15px" /> &nbsp; Milk</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: You can change the height and the width of the image , also the images should be in the same file with the html file. Else you have to include the path in the image source.